# Why can I call a method that changes a member from a const method?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, const-correctness

I'm not sure to understand why I can modify an object from a const method, look:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    int a = 0;
    void change() {
        a = 3;
    }
};

struct Test {
    Foo* f;

    Test(): f{new Foo} {}

    void test() const {
        f->change();
    }
};

int main()
{
  Test t;
  std::cout << "before: " << t.f->a << "\n";
  t.test();
  std::cout << "after: " << t.f->a << "\n";

}
```

Not only it compiles but it prints:

```
0
3
```

So I was able to modify the logical state of an object from a const method. Is that because I used a pointer?

Comment: You don't modify value of `f`. By `f->change()` you modify data pointed by `f`. It is two different things. Try to `f = new ...` inside `test()`, then you will see errror, because you cannot assign new value to `f` inside const method.

Comment: TL;DR. The object that's const within the `test()` member is the `Test` instance, not the dynamic `Foo` instance. You're not modifying `t`, nor any of its concrete members. Lose the pointer and use a concrete `Foo f;` member, then `f.change()` in your const member`test()` and it should puke all over itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `const` applies to the pointer itself, `f`, not to what this pointer is pointing to. The type of `f` inside your `const`-qualified member function, `Test::test()`, is `Foo* const` (i.e., *`const` pointer to `Foo`*), not `const Foo*` (i.e., *pointer to `const Foo`*). That's why you can modify what the pointer is pointing to in spite of the `const` qualification of the member function.

---

Note that the following sample member function, `Test::test2()`, does fail to compile since it is `const`-qualified and tries to modify the pointer data member, `f`:

```
void Test::test2() const {
        f = nullptr; // <-- error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you did not modify the logical state of an object:

```
    f->change();
```

`f`, the object's class member, is as it's always been, here. Its value hasn't changed. It's not pointing to some other object now. It's still pointing to the same object it's always been pointing to.

What you did modify is the object to which `f` points to. Which is a different object.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you modified the **logical** state of the object. That's allowed, because `const` prohibits modifying the **physical** state.

The object `t` has one data member, `f`, whose type is "pointer to Foo". When the `t` object is created, it's `f` member points at an object of type `Foo`. After the call `t.test()` the `f` member still holds the same address, so it points at the same object of type `Foo` as it did before.

If `test()` had tried to change the **value** stored in `f` (i.e., the pointer) the `const` would have prevented it.

```
void Test::test() const { f = new Foo; } // error: `f` is const in this context
```